# Can't get for loop interval in event listener inside loop

Tags: javascript, html, loops, addeventlistener

I have this thing to loop and make a bunch of input fields, plus a check box which clears those in the same row.

```
    var modalBody = document.getElementById("edit-body")
    function createPeriodsEditor(sequence){
     for(var i=1; i<7; i++){
        console.log(i)
        var container = document.createElement("div")
        var hour = document.createElement("input")
        var minute = document.createElement("input")
        var active = document.createElement("input")
        var text = document.createElement("p")

        container.setAttribute("class", "row")
        text.innerHTML = "Period " + i
        hour.setAttribute("class", "column")
        hour.setAttribute("id", "periodInputHourS" + sequence + "P" + i)
        hour.setAttribute("placeholder", "Hour (24 scale)")
        minute.setAttribute("class", "column")
        minute.setAttribute("id", "periodInputMinuteS" + sequence + "P" + i)
        minute.setAttribute("placeholder", "Minute")
        active.setAttribute("type", "checkbox")
        active.setAttribute("id", "periodInputActiveS" + sequence + "P" + i)
        active.setAttribute("class", "column")
        active.setAttribute("checked", "")

        active.addEventListener( 'change', function() {
            console.log(i)
            if(!this.checked) {
                hour.value = ""
                minute.value = ""
            }
        });

        container.appendChild(hour)
        container.appendChild(minute)
        container.appendChild(active)

        modalBody.appendChild(text)
        modalBody.appendChild(container)
    }
}
```

However, for some reason, every check box (id="active") only clears the last input fields created in the row.

When I log i inside the loop, it does it correctly (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) but it only shows 7 no matter which check box (console.log is inside the event listener for check box change) I'm clicking.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try `for(let i=1` - then read about variable scope - difference between let and var - see, once that change handler happens, `i` will be 7, always

Comment: `When I log i inside the loop, it does it correctly (1,2,3,4,5,6,7)` that loop will never output 7 .... only 1,2,3,4,5,6 ... because 7 is not less than 7 - but in the change handler it will ONLY log `7`, because that is the value of `i` at that point - see above to fix